# SQL query on array data in ArcGIS attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, attribute-table, sql, query

I have an attribute table where courses offered by different colleges are in an array, I am trying to Query using ArcGIS query builder so as to return colleges offering a specific course within the array, seems not to be working!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Lists in a column are are inherently *non-relational* (the relational model would use a one-to-many lookup table). ArcGIS doesn't have just one SQL implementation, because every RDBMS  has their own set of non-standard functions, and shapefile, file geodatabase, and Access have their own flavors as well. To make this answerable you'd need to specify the exact storage format, provide a data sample and what you have tried ("not working" is not an adequate problem statement).